# Is it possible to get a SqlDataSource parameter from the ViewState in asp.net web forms?

Tags: webforms, viewstate, sqldatasource, hidden-field

I have a SqlDataSource defined in my aspx file that I use to call a StoredProcedure. It takes a hiddenField as its control parameter.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="input" runat="server" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="input" Name="input" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there a way I can grab that parameter from the ViewState instead? Preferably while keeping the datasource definition in the aspx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in your case is very easy. Just create your own class inherit it from [Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx) and override [Evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.evaluate.aspx) method.

```
[DefaultProperty("ViewStateKey")]
public class ViewStateParameter : Parameter
{
    public string ViewStateKey
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)ViewState["ViewStateKey"] ?? string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ViewStateKey == value)
                return;
            ViewState["ViewStateKey"] = value;

            OnParameterChanged();
        }
    }

    protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control)
    {
        if (control == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewStateKey))
            return null;

        return ViewState[ViewStateKey];
    }
}
```

After that you will be able to use your parameter like following (just remember to register it at the top of your page or in web.config):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <my:ViewStateParameter Name="input" Type="String" ViewStateKey="input" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And your parameter will get its value from viewstate by key `input`.
I dont feel that the code for `ViewStateParameter` is of the first class. Maybe you will want to decorate it with more attributes and/or extra parameter checks with assertions.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem. I dont want to use hidden fields to bind data source parameters because of security reasons.

I have googled one work-around - use asp:label instead of hidden field (make sure Visible=false). And then your label goes to view state and you can bind label to data source parameters.